# Отслеживание выделенного текста WebBrowser WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, webbrowser

Пробоавал

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var doc = TB.Document as mshtml.HTMLDocument;
    if (doc != null)
    {
        var currentSelection = doc.selection;
        if (currentSelection != null)
        {
            var selectionRange = currentSelection.createRange();
            if (selectionRange != null)
            {
                var selectionText = selectionRange.Text;
                lab.Text = selectionText;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

но выдается Ошибка CS1061 об не содержании определения Text.

Может нужно что-то докачать, подключить или проблема в версии .Net?

Требуется проверять после каждого выделение, соответствие выделенного текста с требуемым.
Выделение текста происходит в WebBrowser WPF.
Как это можно реализовать? Или стоит заменить на другой элемент для простоты реализации (но принципиально сохранить простоту вывода HTML страницы)

Comment: `WebBrowser` (Internet Explorer) мёртв, устарел, несовместим с интернетом. Используйте `WebView2` (Edge). https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/wpf